# Comments: How to comment -- or -->

Tags: html

How shall I properly write `--&gt;` or `-->` within a comment?

I am maintaining a large html-file with many tiny entries of program code. Say:

```
a --> b.
```

which I encode in HTML as `--&gt;`:

```
a --&gt; b.
```

However, from time to time, I change an entry and want to comment out the old entry. (Yes, I do have version control in addition to that.) But when I then write

```
<!-- a --&gt; b -->
```

the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) barfs. Indicating that I "forgot" a closing `>`.

1. Is this actually an error or just some overcautious warning?
2. Are there established ways how to "escape" within comments?

Comment: Could you just write the word, "to"?

Comment: @JamesLai Sorry, I don't get it. You want me to change the title?

Comment: I don't know your real situation, but have you considered using a version control system?

Comment: @ComFreek: I do have that, too.

Comment: I personally would come up with a placeholder for `-->`, e.g. `%to%`, and when reading this code replace the placeholder on-the-fly if the language supports it.

Comment: Did you leave off a `!` when writing the comment?  e.g. `<!-- a --&gt; b -->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `CDATA` block to tell the parser to ignore the comment.

```
<![CDATA[ a --> b ]]>
```

It's not quite as nice looking as a comment, but it should pass a validator.

Comment: +1, but I assume that I can now no longer write `]]` in my text. Are these the limitations?

Comment: some more question: Starting with what version is this feature supported? The validator likes it, but Firefox 25.01  shows me `b ]]>` So everything after the closing comment.

Comment: The same thing happened to me in Firefox also.  I did this and it seems to not display anything: `<![CDATA[ a --&gt; b ]]>`